# How to show phone numbers in Google knowledge panel?

Tags: google-search, schema.org, knowledge-graph

I would like to show customer service numbers as shown in attached image in knowledge panel. Where from this information is coming, how to show these in another banking site.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the specific content of the page for which you want to create structured data.

For structured data representing a bank customer support service, you can use the top-level type such as `BankOrCreditUnion` and the property `department`. In turn, in this property, you can embed the type `Organization` which has the property `contactPoint` extensible using the type `ContactPoint` or direct using the property `telephone`. An example of a tree structure:

```
BankOrCreditUnion
        I 
    department --> Organization 
                        I
                      telephone or contactPoint --> ContactPoint 
                                                        I
                                                     telephone
```

Alternative: using the property `contactPoint` (extensible using the type `ContactPoint`) as nested directly in the type `BankOrCreditUnion`.  In this case, you can mark up your customer service using the property `contactType`. The type `ContactPoint` also has the property `telephone`.